# Implementation of push notification

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-2015, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I have created a QUICK START PROJECT in visual studio with AZURE SERVER with the help of the link given below.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started/
and now I want to configure it with push notifications for which I followed the steps show in the link below
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-push/#nodejs
It says to make some changes in the code in the todoitem.js (index.js) from the first link.
I am not able to make those changes can anyone help me with what should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acutally, the `todoitem.js` is in your Mobile App backend server in Node.js. If you have created a Mobile Apps server for your own, you can find and edit this script in **Easy Tables** in your Mobile Apps' manage page in the Azure portal(https://ms.portal.azure.com).
[image]